# Problems navigating to HTML element id using URL hash

Tags: html, scroll, autoscroll

I tried to scroll to a `h4` id in html file by the following code:

```
members.html#goa
```

which works when I open the html file locally; but after I upload the file to the server, it opens the file at the start of the page only. I have
`<h4 id="goa">Goa</h4>` in the `members.html` file. Please help me.

Comment: Does this occur when you click on local links? Are you using any scripts hijacking clicks on local links, such as smooth scrolling? Or does this happen when you type the URL hash manually?

Comment: Hi @agrm, can you please have a look at [link](https://www.isrleaders.club/members.html#goa)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you load [your site](https://www.isrleaders.club/members.html#goa) with Javascript disabled, it does scroll to `#goa` as expected. Thus, it seems you have a piece of code altering the default behavior. On line 35 you have the following:

```
addEventListener("load", function() { setTimeout(hideURLbar, 0); }, false); 
function hideURLbar(){ window.scrollTo(0,1); }
```

I'm not sure why you need this. The whole part looks like a make-shift hack to solve some other issue, and it appears to be hijacking the window scroll. Whenever the document is loaded, it is forced to scroll to the top. Removing the above mentioned code should fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks @agrm for helping me out. I removed the entire `<script>..</script>` and now it's running fine.

Answer (score -2):

You have to write slash '**/**' between filename and id of element you want to scroll to. In your case:

```
members.html/#goa
```

Comment: It resulted in the following error:
`Not Found
The requested URL /members.html/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`
I think that's bcoz the server is trying to open a folder named `members.html` on the root folder.

Comment: This information is simply plain wrong. You do **not** need a slash between the URL path and the fragment identifier. A slash simply indicates that the index file of a subdirectory shall be shown.